# Error to get localstorage object function in Angular5

Tags: typescript, local-storage, angular5, xmpp

I have issue to get localstorage object function while using `CircularJSON.stringify`.
Here is my code

```
//set localstorage data  
localStorage.setItem("client", CircularJSON.stringify(client)); // client is connection object 

//get localstorage data
let client = CircularJSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('client'));
```

while getting the client object only variables are displaying not all the functions

*While set the localstorage*
[image: While set the localstorage]

*While get the localstorage*
[image: while get the localstorage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.stringify() converts the function to NULL or removes the key-value pair from the object. One way could be to serialize the entire function and save it. Later when retrieving, deserialize the functions.

I would not advice saving functions in LocalStorage though.

Comment: I am having a client object of xmpp.createClient (stanza.io), how do I save this object to share it with all of my components in Angular5  or you have any solution to share object function with full life cycle of the app

Comment: Create a global service, inject in the root component to make it a singleton so that only a single instance is used throughout the application. Use this service in any component you need.

Comment: In my service class, I have getter and setter 

get client(): object {
        return this._client;
    }

    set client(value: object) {
        this._client = value;
    }

by this way i can access the concrete object from anywhere, but when i refresh the page the client object becomes undefined and it looses all of its values, so need to store it somewhere, therefore i am using LocalStorage to store this, or there is another way i can persist this object.

Comment: I checked the documentation, there is API for session. On page refresh check if the session is still active if it is active then get the session instance else redirect the user back to the login page.